# bnlearn: print the distribution of a node

Tags: r, bnlearn

I am currently starting to work with the r package bnlearn. I want to create some data, for this purpose I want to use some baysian networks described [here](https://www.bnlearn.com/bnrepository/clgaussian-small.html).

I load a model and then I try to get the distribution for a specific node (conditional or unconditional). How can I get this information?

I am currently only seeing the graph structure of the network.

Edit: I am using the python library rpy2

```py
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = r'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.2'
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
bnlearn = importr('bnlearn')

# loading the model
robjects.r.load('./path/to/healthcare.rda')
df = robjects.globalenv['bn']
model = bnlearn.bn_net(df)

# model has a node 'A'
# I want to do something like
# bnlearn.distribution_of(model, 'A')
```

I am new to programming with r, this might be awful code.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I updated my code. There is nothing special happening,

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that the probability distribution is described in the data frame (df), not the model itself.